# Using Redmine REST API to concurrently update Issues

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

Hoping someone could shed some light as my searches have turned up very little information.

I want to use [Redmine's REST API for Issues](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) to do:

1. `GET /issues/[id].json` to get the content of a specific issue.
2. Make changes to the above content.
3. Finally `PUT /issues/[id].json` the content back.

But I want to perform this using some form of concurrency control (ideally optimistic locking), so that *content* isn't changed by someone else around *2*, promptly followed by *3* destroying said change.

This link hints on such possibility:

- [redmine.exceptions.ConflictError](http://python-redmine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/exceptions.html#redmine.exceptions.ConflictError) - (Why does this class exist?)

I'd assume there'd be some way of specifying a *compare* value, possibly `updated_on`, to do compare-and-swap-esk locking with `PUT /issues/[id].json`, but I can't find anything regarding this.

Redmine's web interface provides a concurrency control mechanism, so I'm stumped as to why there's so little information on this.

Comment: Standard concurrency control mechanism works the same way in html web interface and in API calls. You should get an error when trying to save a stale object: https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/controllers/issues_controller.rb#L181

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to make that fire via the API.  (I tried adding things like `version`, `last_journal_id`, etc. to the issue JSON when `PUT`ing.)  I did however find `409 Conflict` documented for wikis: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_WikiPages#Creating-or-updating-a-wiki-page.